# how to configure xivo for WebRTC

Tags: linux, asterisk, webrtc

I used this document to test the implementation of the webrtc on my website

https://flashphoner.com/call-from-browser-to-mobile/

But I do not want to use their WCS5 server but my xivo pabx server.

so I wanted to know what is the configuration that must be set up on my pabx server to allow the connection of websocket